# Android Emulator Does Not Start

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have installed all of the necessary parts and the ADT plugin for Eclipse. When I create an Android virtual device and start it, nothing appears. I get the box where the green status bar shows up and says 'Starting emulator for AVD'. However, nothing appears afterwards. No logs in the Console either....does anyone have any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You will have more chances to debug the issue if you start emulator with “emulator” command:

```
emulator @avd-name
```

“avd-name” is your emulator image name as you created it.

And if you don't happen to have “emulator” command, try adding “android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/” (where android-sdk-linux_x86 is your android SDK installation directory) to your PATH.

Comment: I'm on a windows environment. Can you please tell me how to do this in Windows

Comment: Approximately, since I don't use Windows. To run the “emulator @avd-name”, you open a console by I think doing Start → Run → type “cmd” → click OK or whatever the confirm button is. The “cmd” is the windows command-line interface. Next, once you've got that black window, the console, try running the “emulator” command I've mentioned earlier.

Comment: As for setting the PATH variable, if you don't know how to do it please google with your particular Windows version since it's different for different versions (e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=edit+environment+variables+windows+7). After setting it, you might need to restart the console.

Comment: or just go where the emulator exe is located and type what user1410657 told you ... I really dont get why everytime people make a fuss about windows os :P

Comment: Sounds like android SDK bug on windows, see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue for a bit and realized it was because when you set the skin it is default set to WVGA800 but for whatever reason it only worked if that was set to HVGA.

Comment: @niccosuave yoou just made my day

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem is the graphic card. The emulator may not recognize you graphic card try again with another one.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu (I use Xubuntu):

Mine Android Virtual Devices didn't started because i used NVIDIA drivers for ubuntu.
After changing drivers to Nouveau it booted in 15sec.

Go to "Settings Manager" -> Software & Updated -> Additional Drivers
chose: "Using X.org x server -- Nouveau display driver (open source)"

NVIDIA F# U
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55XVnJ_0qhg

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. 
Windows 7.
ADT Bundle 64-bit.
I was logging in to my PC with Active Directory credentials(corporate).
Emulator was not starting at all, after I tried many different things.
I switched to a local administrator login, and everything worked.

This is not necessarily the solution. I would rather want to know how to make it work on my AD account.

Answer (score 0):

This also is related to the screen size of the emulator.

I created a fresh AVD with a 768x1280 display. This starts fine. Then I replaced the values of `lcd.height`, `lcd.width`, `skin.name`, `skin.path` in the config files to represent 1080x1920. After that the emulator does not start anymore.

I start the emulators inside a Xvnc session with 1360x768 pixels, but it also does not work in a Xvnc session with 3000x2000 pixels.